# Sugarcrm loading One to One relationship with Bean

Tags: relationship, sugarcrm, one-to-one

**What i have :**
I have users, which could be related with other users.

Not like 'parents' or 'referer', but like "assistante"

So, i've created a one-to-one relationship between users and... users. My table name is "users_users_1_c". My first user'id is stocked in users_users_1users_idb and my assistante'id is stocked under users_users_1users_ida.

**What i Want :**

I have to write a logic hook, and in that one, i have to fetch if the users has an assistante.

**What i tried :**

So, i tried `$myUser->load_relationship('users_users_1_c');` and `$myUser->load_relationship->('users');`

i tested both with the code below (by changing the relationship's name, of course)

`if($myUser->load_relationship('users'){
var_dump("Relationship!");die();
}`

But nothing happened.

**What i know :**

I've read these and tested these solutions, but they didn't work either :

[John Dope's get_related_bean links](http://johndopenotes.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/sugarcrm-get-related-records-using-get_linked_beans/)

[Sugar's doc about fetching relationships](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/SugarBean/01_Fetching_Relationships/)

So, please, could you tell me how to load a one-to-one relationship, and better, to load a relationship between two records of the same module, by using the bean, please? Or, i'll do it very dirtily by using pure SQL... And that would be a shame.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure that the "_c" is used in the relationship names, so try load_relationship('users_users_1')

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the getBeans() method on the Link class. Works like this:

```
$myUser->load_relationship('users_users_1_c');
$user_list = $myUser->users_users_1_c->getBeans();
foreach($user_list as $user){
  // handle $user that you found
}
```

An alternative shorthand:

```
$myUser->load_relationship('users_users_1_c');
foreach($myUser->users_users_1_c->getBeans() as $user){
  // handle $user that you found
}
```

All of this assumes that `users_users_1_c` is the correct name of the relationship. To verify, or double check, dig in to /custom/modules/Users/Ext/Vardefs/vardefs.ext.php and look at the different relationship names.